# Trusted Daemon Issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, balance

I'm trying to use the GUI and I synced my wallet through a remote node then I changed it to localhost. When I try to rescan my balance it warns me that I should use a trusted daemon. Isn't my local node a trusted daemon? If not how can I make it trusted?

Is it possible doing on GUI or do I have to do it on console?

Comment: Are you sure the wallet is actually connected to the local node?